# Regex entre palavras

Tags: c#, regex

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta `Regex` que me retorne em um arquivo de código fonte  as declarações que não sejam public `%%Enum Tipo`, porém não sou muito familiarizado com `Regex` e estou tendo um pouco de dificuldade, alguém tem alguma dica de como possa fazer isso.

Basicamente essa `Regex` teria que me retornar as declarações:

```
public int Tipo
public int16 Tipo
```

ou seja, todas que o tipo não termine com `Enum` como por exemplo:

```
public CaixaTipoEnum Tipo
```

Comment: tá difícil de entender o que você quer e o que está acontecendo. Reescreva a pergunta usando pontuação e formatação nos códigos.

Comment: Também não costumo usar `RegEx`. Só para lhe dar uma dica, já é possível achar o que você quer semanticamente que é muito melhor. Claro que não é a forma mais simples, precisa aprender uma API mais complexa, mas se não for só isto que precisa, esta ferramenta pode ser útil: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a seguinte expressão `^(public|private)((?!Enum).)*$`.

Usei um testador de expressão regular online [Clique aqui](http://tools.lymas.com.br/regexp_br.php#),

cole a expressão lá e poderá testar.

Comment: Eu ia editar minha resposta para algo parecido (`^((?!Enum).)*$`) depois de ver [esta resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) no SO, mas você chegou primeiro. Fique com meu +1 :)

Comment: heheh.. foi a mesma resposta que eu encontrei, só incrementei na expressão a parte `(public|private)`, que vi na sua resposta! :)

Comment: Então, usando a expressão `(^((?!Enum).)*$)` como faço para editar ela que após o `Enum` tenha o termo `Tipo`

Comment: Você quer pegar as expressões que contenham o Tipo depois do Enum? `public CaixaTipoEnum Tipo` é isso?

Comment: @PabloVargas troca `Enum` por `(Enum.*Tipo)`.

Answer (score 1):

Força bruta nunca me falhou.

Primeiro você pega todas as declarações de membros com a expressão:

```
(public|private) .+?;
```

Ponha isso numa lista. Depois, sobre a lista, você pega os que você **não** quer com a expressão:

```
Enum
```

Sim, simples assim.

Agora é só pegar todos os elementos que fazem parte da primeira lista, mas que não fazem parte da segunda ;)